# Listening channels redis in node.js

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

There is such a simple code wiretapping channels radishes.

```
redisClient = redis.createClient();
redisDummyPublishClient = redis.createClient();
//redisClient.auth("25c9721b4e579fc5af961f944e23f46f");


//look for connection errors and log
redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("error event - " + redisClient.host + ":" + redisClient.port + " - " + err);
});


var channels_active = [];
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    redisClient.on('ready', function() {
    redisClient.psubscribe('*');
  });


  function CreateSocketsAccept (eventNameListen, channel, message){
    var obj = { channel : channel, message : message}
      for (i in eventNameListen) {
          io.sockets.in(channel).emit(eventNameListen[i], obj);
       } 
    }

  redisClient.on('pmessage', function(pattern, channel, message) {
    console.log(channel);
    CreateSocketsAccept(channels_active, channel, message);
  });     

});

setInterval(function() {
  var no = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  redisDummyPublishClient.publish('478669c7fa549970e36eac591cdca62e', 'Generated random no ' + no);
}, 5000);
```

Send data from PHP:

```
$this->load->library( 'rediska_connector' );
// Other way to publish
$rediska = new Rediska();
$rediska->publish('realtime', 'PHP SENDING');
```

The question is, why does not output to the console the names of available channels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>As far as I'm aware, you can't listen on all channels...</s>

If you want to subscribe to a pattern, you need to use `psubscribe`:

```
redisClient.psubscribe('*');
```

And instead of listening for `message` events, listen for `pmessage` events:

```
redisClient.on('pmessage', function(pattern, channel, message) {
  console.log(channel);
});
```

(thanks @DidierSpezia for correcting me :)

**EDIT:** you can't mix `socket.io` and the Redis client like that, you need to move the Redis code outside the `socket.io` handler:

```
// No need for this because it's doing nothing:
// io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { ... });

redisClient.on('ready', function() {
  redisClient.psubscribe('*');
});

function CreateSocketsAccept (eventNameListen, channel, message){
  var obj = { channel : channel, message : message}
  for (i in eventNameListen) {
    io.sockets.in(channel).emit(eventNameListen[i], obj);
  }
}

redisClient.on('pmessage', function(pattern, channel, message) {
  console.log(channel);
  CreateSocketsAccept(channels_active, channel, message);
});
```

Comment: Well, you can - but you need to use subscription patterns (i.e. psubscribe and listen to "pmessage")

Comment: @DidierSpezia thanks for the correction :) I'll see if `node-redis` supports `PSUBSCRIBE` and edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, but not work. I edited my code above in question, look please, here is console.log(channel);

Comment: Can you explain, what i would set instead parametr "pattern"?

Comment: @OlegPonomarchuk you don't set it, it's the pattern (`*` in this case) that causes the `pmessage` event to call the handler. If you would have subscribed to the pattern `test*` with `psubscribe`, the `pattern` argument would also contain `test*`.